# Set widget options in iscrollview

Tags: iscroll

I'm using [iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview) to use iScroll in a jquery mobile project. This widget provides certain options that can be set, including the 'createScroller', which I would like to set to false.
Unfortunately, I fail to get this actually working when I set it like this:

```
<div data-iscroll="{'createScroller': false}">...</div>
```

Does anybody know how to set this option? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The options should be in JSON strict format - everything but numeric values and booleans have to be enclosed in **double quotes**. It's exactly the opposite of your example ;)

```
<div data-iscroll='{"createScroller": false}'>...</div>
```